# Auto Complete feature not working when adding second tag on Stack Exchange websites

Tags: support, tags

The below snapshot will clear the question that I am asking. When I clicked on the `Tags` for first time when I was asking this question, I got this result:

> [image]

On Clicking second time, to add second tag, I got this result:

> [image]

This time, I didn't get and auto-complete feature, i.e., all the tags that should be suggested to me for this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no tag suggestion feature.

The first time you clicked, you were shown the *required* tags; you cannot post a question on a Meta site without one of those tags. They are not a suggestion.

Once you have added a required tag, the site makes no attempts to suggest tags.

Comment: OK, there are no tag suggestions, but there should be something that will not make us invent new tag. Many people don't have required points. It should automatically narrow down to already declared tag.

Comment: It already does that. Just start typing.

Comment: OK. I forgot that.